# Google Chrome -causing major lag

Tags: performance, google-chrome

One of the websites that I work with has been having up to 17 seconds of content not showing. However once it connects the site loads fairly fast. I tracked the issue down to a Google Chrome bug where the "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" when enabled causes these extreme page loads. If I disable it then I don't see these page loads anymore.

Is anyone familiar with what may cause this glitch and what can be done if anything from the server side?

Answer (score 1):

We ended up discovering that a plugin was loading its own version of JQuery and that it was causing a large issue because it was being injected right after the opening body tag of the website. After talking with the developer we resolved the issue and all is well. Hope this helps anyone else with a similar issue.

**Our Problem:**

- Multiple Jquery Versions On Website
- Issues With Javascript Placement On Site

**Our Fix:**

- Worked with Jquery plugin author to remove calls to JQuery
- Moved Javascript files to the bottom of the HTML document
- Loaded Javascript files asynchronously if supported